# Calling a matcher function inside a try while reading continuous data using GNU

Tags: java, regex, serial-port

```
case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:

      byte[] readBuffer = new byte[64];
     try {
            // read data
            int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
            inputStream.close();
            //-------------------------------
           //send the received data to the GUI
            String result = new String(readBuffer,0,numBytes);
            //-----------------------------
            gui.setjtaReceived(result);

            matcher(result,writer,df);
            //gui.setjtaReceived(result);
     }
     catch (IOException e) {exceptionReport(e);}
```

In the above switch case for SerialPortEvent.Dat_Available, I'm receiving continuous data in real time. The matcher function calls for the below defined function

```
    private void matcher(String str,FileWriter writer,DateFormat df) {
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(str);
    Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(str);
    System.out.println(m1.group());
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String match_heartBeat = null;
    String match1 = m1.group();
    int length1 = match1.length();
    if(m2.find()){
        String match2 = m2.group();
        int length2 = match2.length();
        match_heartBeat = match2.substring(2, length2-1);
        //System.out.println(match1.subSequence(2, 4) + ";" + match_heartBeat);
    }
    String realTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
    writer.append(realTime);
    writer.append(',');
    writer.append(match1.subSequence(2, length1-1));
    writer.append(',');
    writer.append(match_heartBeat);
    writer.append('\n');
    writer.flush();


 }
```

When I tried writing to an external csv file or even doing a System.out.println(m1.group) or System.out.println(match_heartBeat), I couldn't write it to the file or print to screen. however System.out.println(m1) is printed on screen. Any idea how to overcome this? I'm trying to decode the data received in realtime. 
The pattern is as follows:

```
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\b(a)\\w*( )\\b");
    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("\\b(')\\w*( )\\b");
```

It looks for alphabet 'a' until space and ' to space. The file 'writer' is generated once the program starts running. But could append the decoded data.

Sample data:

```
79 0009a017 009a047 9%0009a047 90009a046 9%0009a0469 0009a045 9%0009a0459'00 90009a045 9%0009a044 90009a044 9%0009a044 9
```

Sample output
CSV file

```
System time , 17 , 00
```

Comment: What do you mean by "alphabet a"? `(a)` will just capture the `a` character in a group, you don't even need the parentheses here if you don't want to catpure the a. Same goes for the space and the quote.

Comment: And you didn't tell what you wanted to capture either. Give sample input data and what you want as a result.

Comment: The above string will be a the sample data. Following a there will 017 and a space. This string is read through the serial port from a device.

Comment: oh so how will my pattern be defined? thank you

Comment: Please edit your post to include that sample data and what you want out of it

Comment: On running the above program, I couldn't append the file or get a value for m1.group(); 
is this because of continous flow of data or any logical issues with my code?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't understand, is this really all you want to extract? Where does that come from?

Comment: its being generated by an external machine through a serial port.The sample data is similar to wat the machine sends. This data is read and then decoded.What i'm trying to do is decode as and when i receive it.

Comment: OK, but I don't see how your sample data relates to the CSV at all. Please be more specific.

Comment: I'm appending the System time , 17 , 00
17 comes from pattern p1 and 00 comes from pattern p2. 
i defined a 
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("test.csv");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's clarify the specification based on the comments.  This is the input string:

79 0009a017 009a047

This is the output string:

```
017,00
```

And "017" is a decimal (not octal) number.  It may be convient to format it as "17" later.

As was mentioned in the comments, this regular expression is incorrect:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\b(a)\\w*( )\\b");
```

It should be:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("a(\\d+) (\\d{2})");
```

Quick demonstration:

```
echo "79 0009a017 009a047" | perl -lne 'print $1,",",$2 if /a(\d+) (\d{2})/'
017,00
```